# Requst object couldnt identified in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created a new .cshtml file. URL of this view is: `mypage?id=1`

When I want to get value of `id` in URL with using `Request.Params["id"]` it doesn't return any value.

Actually `Request` object isn't seen on this view. I use it in another page it works fine. I don't understand why `Request` isn't available on new page.

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's not possible to tell you why you can't access the Request object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not really a good design to access querystring parameters in a view. I would recommend putting id into a View Model and accessing it from there. Or another option would be passing the value of id into the view using the ViewBag, for example:

**Controller**

```
Public ActionResult MyPage(int id)
{
    ViewBag.Id = id;
    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
<Some Code....>
    <div>
        @ViewBag.Id
    </div>
</Some Code....>
```